# Mime to CD Conversion: missing informations

Tags: lotus-domino

I've a Lotusscript agent that scan an inbox and perform some operations on its email.

In particular, one of these has a Body field with some infomations (formatting, text and so on).

When agent starts, i can see this log on server:

```
Begin MIME to CD Conversion (Process: Agent Manager (000016AB:0000004A), Database: XXXXX)
End MIME to CD Conversion (Process: Agent Manager (000016AB:0000004A), Database: XXXXX)
```

After that, a lot of information contained in body field are lost.

How to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

Immediately after you create your NotesSession (e.g., `dim s as new NotesSesion`), add this to your code:

```
s.convertMIME = false
```